# Adding JQuery/Javascript into my web page

Tags: jquery, html

i know this question has been answered many times before. But im really stuck on trying to implement jquery into my webpage and im just not sure where im going wrong. Ive tried the 2 ways people offer i.e:

adding this into my html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and downloading jquery-1.11.3.min into my source file (where everything is saved). Then adding this into my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WPKEY/106website/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

neither work unfortunately :( here is my JFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pxejv9p3/ 
any help would be appreciated rather than flagging this for repeating a question. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: what is not working?please include relevant code and explanation.

Comment: @Pekka well on the jfiddle the jquery is showing up?

Comment: How do you know jQuery is not working? What are you doing exactly and in what order?

Comment: i assume jquery is loaded properly otherwise the console with return `$ undefined` so what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have add `<script src="myScript.js"></script>` wrong place.

Please move this syntax after

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WPKEY/106website/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please check & confirm.
I hope this work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Only load 1 copy of jquery, you currently have 3.
Include your myScript.js after the jquery.  Fiddle isn't great for this, but this should get you going in the right direction.